Can I put polyurethane on a wood shelf after polishing it with liquid gold
I used liquid gold to dust a shelf. Is it ok to now put polyurethane on it

Can you be more specific about the ‘liquid gold’ product? A web search turns up many things with that name.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. You need to be specific about all details here. In addition to the "liquid gold" product you need to tell us which polyurethane (there are 3 main types; you likely mean only 1 of 2 of them and which type is critical). We could also do with knowing how extensively the gold is applied, plus there's how you plan to apply the poly — brush-application is significantly more abrasive than using a roller, and spraying isn't abrasive at all — so you can see that intended application method might be key, depending on how durable the gold is, how the 2 products interact etc.

@Graphus  Your comment re; 3 types interested and confused me so I went searching for more info on 3 types.  I found this site discussing 7 types: https://www.obsessedwoodworking.com/7-types-of-polyurethane-woodworking-finish-and-when-to-use-each/  I don't know if this is the type of categorization you meant and would love for you to do one of your Q/A posts explaining the three types and their applications.

@Ashlar, ugh, this might seem like just splitting hairs but those aren't all types. As soon as one gets to wipe-on mentioned as a type one should immediately pause and go "Hey wait a sec..." because that is of course merely diluted oil-based. Similarly spray poly is just poly in a spraycan! That has absolutely nothing to say about it being a type, any more than spray shellac is actually different shellac to stuff mixed at home. The three types or categories of poly are two-part (generally used by pros only), oil-based and waterbased, because they're completely different categories of finish.

@Ashlar, I've actually referred to this previously, I thought multiple times but the others must be Comments as I can't locate them. So there's this.

@graphus  Maybe I need to do more research before commenting! :)
